# VS Code extension to add templates of React/Redux Components

Tags: reactjs, vscode-extensions

Can some one tell me what is the name of the extension of VS code that is used for creating templates of react/redux Components??

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets by `dsznajder` and read the extension docs for different component snippets.

Answer (score 1):

ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets
then type rcfe for react functional
rcc for class component